# How to retrieve specific javascript object including key

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects

javascript object skeleton

```
var users = {};

users = {
  '123': {
    name: 'Lucky',
    gender: 'female'
  },

  '456': {
    name: 'K',
    gender: 'male'
  }
}
```

Requirement: i want to retrieve 123 and it's objects by search key (ex: 123)

```
'123':  
 { name: 'Lucky',  
     gender: 'female' }
```

similarly if key is 456, i want to retrieve

```
'456':  
   { name: 'K',  
     gender: 'male' }  
 }
```

Comment: So, what have you tried so far to achieve this as your requirement is quite simple.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

Comment: `users['123']` , `users['456']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean dynamic property access? Use [] notation for that.

Inn Javascript, to access an object's property 'xyz' , there's two notations:

```
obj.xyz
```

and

```
ob['xyz']
```

```js
var users = {
  '123': {
    name: 'Lucky',
    gender: 'female'
  },

  '456': {
    name: 'K',
    gender: 'male'
  }
}

function getUserById(usermap, id) {
  try {
    return { [id]: usermap[id] }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

console.log(getUserById(users, '456'));
```

Comment: I think OP wants to return the key too.

Comment: Adjusted the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply check if the property exists, and return it if it does:

```js
var users = {};

users = {
  '123': {
    name: 'Lucky',
    gender: 'female'
  },

  '456': {
    name: 'K',
    gender: 'male'
  }
};

const search = s => s && users[s] && {[s]: users[s]}

console.log(search('123'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple - use array notation:

```js
const users = {
  '123': {
    name: 'Lucky',
    gender: 'female'
  },

  '456': {
    name: 'K',
    gender: 'male'
  }
}

const getObjectByNum = n => ({ [n]: users[n] }) || "Not found";

console.log(getObjectByNum(123));
console.log(getObjectByNum(456));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: I think OP wants the key returned too.

Comment: Just saw that @Kobe - fixed now.